# Make an ID a String jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a jQuery function that calls an API. The result sends me back some data. There is a piece of data I need to work with.

I'm trying to replace teamId = 100 with "Blue Team" and teamId = 200 with (Read Team).

I just need a variable that checks if the ID is 100 and makes the value of the variable "blue" and if its 200 then "red"

I've got this:

```
        function generateTeamHtml(teamId, participants)  {
      var teamNum = "team"+teamId;
      var html = '<table id="' + teamNum + '">';
      html += '<thead>';
      html += '<tr><th colspan="2">';
      html += teamNum;
      html += '</th></tr>';
      html += '<tr><th>   Summoner Name   </th><th>   Summoner Id   </th></tr>';
      html += '</thead><tbody>';
      for ( userNum in participants) {
        var user = participants[userNum];
        var team = user.teamId;
        var summonerName = user.summonerName;
        var summonerId = user.summonerId;
        if (team == teamId) {
          html += '<tr><td>' + summonerName + '</td><td>' + summonerId + '</td></tr>';
        }
      }
      html += '</tbody></table>';
      return html;
    }
```

So in the table I see either "team100" or "team 200" 
I would like a variable called

```
var = teamColour
```

Team Colour should take "teamId" and say if the id is 100 then make "teamColour" Blue if "teamId" make "teamColour" Red.

Thankyou!

Comment: Can you show some code ? What stuffs have you tried ?

Comment: Sure I've got this: var teamNum = "team"+teamId;  So in the table I see either "team100" or "team 200"  I would like a variable called "teamColour" which takes "teamId" and says if the id is 100 then make "teamColour" Blue if "teamId" make "teamColour" Red. Does that help?

Comment: @InchHigh Fix your post so it contains code, don't post code in comments.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my post to include the pieces of code :)

Comment: @inchHigh Did you read the link I posted that teaches you how to ask a good question? You have to post code we can run. Your question is extremely vague. Don't try to explain it with words. Show code, show input, show output, show expected/actual behavior

Comment: I think I have enough of what you may need to help me? Sorry I don't really know what you'll need to help me. I can add the variable into the jQuery that builds the table. I just can figure out how to simply define a parameter that can then check if Team = 100 then set text to "Blue" if Team = 200 then set text to "Red". teamName would be my preferred variable name?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your model should come with that information directly from that api, but, if it is impossible... you can map that ids with a some data reducer, like what follow:

```js
var getTeamColor = (function(teamsMap) {
  
  return function(teamId) {
    teamId = Number((/(\d+)/.exec(teamId) || []).pop());


    if(teamsMap.hasOwnProperty(teamId)) {
      return teamsMap[teamId];
    }
  };
})({
  100: "blue",
  200: "red"
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var team1 = document.getElementById('team100');
  var team2 = document.getElementById('team200');
  
  team1.style.backgroundColor = getTeamColor(team1.id);
  team2.style.backgroundColor = getTeamColor(team2.id);

});
```

```css
div { width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 25px; float:left; color: #fff; padding: 25px 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 2em; }
```

```html
<div id="team100">
  team 100
</div>

<div id="team200">
  team 200
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work! :( thanks for trying though.

Comment: I made an edit, but, for the future you should provide a use-case of what you are doing.

Comment: @InchHigh "Doesn't work" is not very helpful What exactly doesn't work and how did you use this function. Your question is unclear. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not sure I placed it where I thought it needed to be. My error box's are always blank now since someone else did work on my site.

Comment: You shouldn't copy/past code without trying to understand it

Comment: I have updated my question. Is there enough information on it now?